# Why do i never get to on_connect in ShadyHttpClient

Tags: ruby, event-driven

So witness and observe the following code, my questions is why do i never make it to the on_connect after starting the cool.io loop in send_to_server, the l.run should fire off the request as per the documented example on the github, and how the code handles incoming connections in module Server `@socket.attach(l)
l.run`

which does work and accepts the incoming data and sends it to my parser, which does work and fires off all the way up until the aforementioned send_to_server. So what is going on here?

```
require 'cool.io'
require 'http/parser'
require 'uri'

class Hash
  def downcase_key
    keys.each do |k|
      store(k.downcase, Array === (v = delete(k)) ? v.map(&:downcase_key) : v)
    end
    self
  end
end

module ShadyProxy
  extend self

  module ClientParserCallbacks
    extend self

    def on_message_complete(conn)
      lambda do
        puts "on_message_complete"
        PluginHooks.before_request_to_server(conn)
      end
    end

    def on_headers_complete(conn)
      lambda do |headers|
        conn.headers = headers
      end
    end

    def on_body(conn)
      lambda do |chunk|
        conn.body << chunk
      end
    end

  end

  module PluginHooks
    extend self

    def before_request_to_server(conn)
      # modify request here
      conn.parser.headers.delete "Proxy-Connection"
      conn.parser.headers.downcase_key
      send_to_server(conn)
    end

    def send_to_server(conn)
      parser = conn.parser
      uri = URI::parse(parser.request_url)
      l = Coolio::Loop.default
      puts uri.scheme + "://" + uri.host
      c = ShadyHttpClient.connect(uri.scheme + "://" + uri.host,uri.port).attach(l)
      c.connection_reference = conn
      c.request(parser.http_method,uri.request_uri)
      l.run

    end

    def before_reply_to_client(conn)

    end

  end

  class ShadyHttpClient < Coolio::HttpClient

    def connection_reference=(conn)
      puts "haz conneciton ref"
      @connection_reference = conn
    end

    def connection_reference
      @connection_reference
    end

    def on_connect
      super
      #never gets here
      @headers = nil
      @body = ''
      @buffer = ''
    end

    def on_connect_failed
      super
      # never gets here either 
    end

    def on_response_header(header)
      @headers = header
    end

    def on_body_data(data)
      puts "on data?"
      @body << data
      STDOUT.write data
    end

    def on_request_complete
      puts "Headers"
      puts @headers
      puts "Body"
      puts @body
    end


    def on_error(reason)
      STDERR.puts "Error: #{reason}"
    end

  end

  class ShadyProxyConnection < Cool.io::TCPSocket
    attr_accessor :headers, :body, :buffer, :parser

    def on_connect
      @headers = nil
      @body = ''
      @buffer = ''
      @parser = Http::Parser.new
      @parser.on_message_complete = ClientParserCallbacks.on_message_complete(self)
      @parser.on_headers_complete = ClientParserCallbacks.on_headers_complete(self)
      @parser.on_body = ClientParserCallbacks.on_body(self)
    end

    def on_close
      puts "huh?"
    end

    def on_read(data)
      @buffer << data
      @parser << data 
    end

  end

  module Server
    def run(opts)
      begin
      # Start our server to handle connections (will raise things on errors)
      l = Coolio::Loop.new
      @socket = Cool.io::TCPServer.new(opts[:host],opts[:port], ShadyProxy::ShadyProxyConnection)
      @socket.attach(l)
      l.run
      # Handle every request in another thread
      loop do
        Thread.new s = @socket.accept
      end 
      # CTRL-C
      rescue Interrupt
        puts 'Got Interrupt..'
      # Ensure that we release the socket on errors
      ensure
        if @socket
          @socket.close
          puts 'Socked closed..'
        end
        puts 'Quitting.'
      end

    end

    module_function :run
  end

end

ShadyProxy::Server.run(:host => '0.0.0.0',:port => 1234)
```